# Polynomials have smallest degree

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, polynomials

I am interested in the following problem.

**Problem 1.** *Find polynomial P (x) has integer coefficients, there is no rational roots, with the smallest degree such that for each positive integer $m$ there exists a positive integer a such that $$m \mid P (a). $$*
In the case of $\deg P = 2$, use quadratic residue, we can see that it cannot happen.

In the case of $\deg P = 4$, I have the answer (use quadratic residue).

Therefore, I need an answer for the case of $\deg P = 3$, ie the following problem.

**Problem 2.** *Let the polynomial $ P (x) = ax ^ 3 + bx ^ 2 + cx + d$, $a,\,b,\,c,\,d\in\mathbb Z$ and $a \ne 0 $, $ P (x) $ is irreducible on $ \mathbb Z [x] $. Prove that there exists a positive integer $ m $ such that $$m\nmid P(n),\quad\forall\,n\in\mathbb N^*.$$*

Comment: $d$ is integer, edited!

Comment: @Drona can you post your solution for p=2 and 4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems this is a corollary of the Chebotarev density theorem.  See e.g. [these notes](http://websites.math.leidenuniv.nl/algebra/Lenstra-Chebotarev.pdf), Ex. 7.2(b):
Let $ f \in \mathbb Z[X]$ be an irreducible polynomial with the property that $(f \mod p)$ has a zero in $\mathbb F_p$ for all but finitely many primes $p$.  Prove that $f$ has degree $1$.

In particular, in your problem 2 there are infinitely many primes that work for $m$.

Comment: Thanks Robert !!